# How to forward an email with attachments using Python

Tags: python, email, email-attachments

I need to write a program that checks a gmail inbox using `imaplib` and forwards out emails that do not match a specific subject to a separate email. I can do this using `stmplib` but I do not know how to do it if the email that needs to be forwarded out and deleted contains an attachment. The following is my code that I need to update to be able to handle emails with attachments.

```
# Connect and login to email
imap = imaplib.IMAP4_SSL('imap.gmail.com')
imap.login('user@gmail.com','password')
imap.list()
imap.select('inbox')

smtp = smtplib.SMTP_SSL('smtp.gmail.com')
smtp.login('user@gmail.com','password')

try:
    #Search and return sequential ids
    result, data = imap.search(None,'ALL') 
    ids_list = data[0].split()
    #print 'Total emails: '+str(len(ids_list))
    latest_id = ids_list[-1]

    #Process each email in inbox
    for i in ids_list:
        t, d = imap.fetch(i, '(RFC822)')
        for res_part in d:
            if isinstance(res_part, tuple):
                text = res_part[1]
                msg = email.message_from_string(text)
                subject = msg['subject']
                #print 'Subject: '+subject
                message = get_txt(msg) #Retrieves email body text
                #print message
                if subject != 'The subject I\'m looking for': #Junk email
                    #print 'Sending to another email...'
                    smtp.sendmail('from@gmail.com', 'to@email.com', message)
                    imap.store(i, '+FLAGS', '\\Deleted')
                    imap.expunge()
                else: #Email we need to process
                    #print 'Process this email'

except IndexError:
    #Inbox is empty
```

Can somebody show me the proper way to accomplish this? Thanks!

Comment: @abccd I've updated with the current code that I have. I need it to be able to handle email attachments while it currently only handles the body of an email.

Answer (score 0):

To use this library you need an working SMTP server. You can use the one of you email provider, or you can setup one for yourself.

After this is done you cannot as a link, as example for an FTP server, on which you file is laying. This should also be supported with POP.